# Getting an icloud entitlement error when uploading iOS build to app center

Tags: xcode, react-native, icloud, entitlements, visual-studio-app-center

I am getting the following iCloud error.

> Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "exportOptionsPlist error
>   for key 'iCloudContainerEnvironment': expected one of {Development,
>   Production}, but no value was provided"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=exportOptionsPlist error for key
>   'iCloudContainerEnvironment': expected one of {Development,
>   Production}, but no value was provided}

I have the following entitlements for iCloud.

```
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
</array>

<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-development-container-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
</array>
```

I've tried putting "Development" and "Production" for the string value instead of `iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier)`. However, Xcode and app center gives me an error saying Provisioning profile doesn't match the entitlements value.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with Ionic and I solved like this

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod --release -- --iCloudContainerEnvironment=Production
```

Probably in react-native you can also pass additional flags at build time.

More info:

- https://medium.com/@michele.patrassi/https-medium-com-michele-patrassi-add-icloud-icloudcontainerenvironment-to-your-ionic-ios-app-227300bf8896